# Splitting a pandas column on multiple delimiters and then converting them into rows

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Currently my dataset is as:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | str1/value1,str2/value21,value22,value23,str3/value31,value32 |
| 2 | str4/value4,str5/value51,value52,value53,str6/value61,value62 |

I want to first split data on a comma (',') and then on the ('/'), but I want to keep all the occurrences after '/' with a comma. Also, I need to split them into row values.

The output should be:

| ID | str | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | str1 | value1 |
| 1 | str2 | value21,value22,value23 |
| 1 | str3 | value31,value32 |
| 2 | str4 | value4 |
| 2 | str5 | value51,value52,value53 |
| 2 | str6 | value61,value62 |

Please can somebody help me do it in an efficient way, instead of looping it for each and every occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a double split with a regex:

```
df['str'] = df['value'].str.split(r',(?=[^/,]+/)')
df = df.explode('str')
df[['str', 'value']] = df['str'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

output:

```
   ID                    value   str
0   1                   value1  str1
0   1  value21,value22,value23  str2
0   1          value31,value32  str3
1   2                   value4  str4
1   2  value51,value52,value53  str5
1   2          value61,value62  str6
```

Or, generating a new dataframe, with `extractall` and named capturing groups + a `join`:

```
df2 = (df[['ID']]
       .join(df['value']
             .str.extractall(r'(?P<str>[^,/]+)/(?P<value>[^/]+?)(?=,[^,]+/|$)')
             .droplevel(1))
      )
```

output:

```
   ID   str                    value
0   1  str1                   value1
0   1  str2  value21,value22,value23
0   1  str3          value31,value32
1   2  str4                   value4
1   2  str5  value51,value52,value53
1   2  str6          value61,value62
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LUvoZC/1)